# How do I multiplicate values of an existing pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe from a csv file and I plotted it.

It looks like this: [image]

I want to multiplicate the values of the `'W'` column by 1000 in order to have values of 1600 instead of 1.6. How do I implement that in my code?

I was trying the `mul` function but it did not work:

```
xcolumn_list1 = ['W']
xcolumn_list1.mul(1000)
geyser_June_e2[xcolumn_list1].plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You need assign the values back - `geyser_June_e2[xcolumn_list1] = geyser_June_e2[xcolumn_list1] * 1000`? or shorthand `geyser_June_e2[xcolumn_list1] *= 1000`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `.mul()` for a List. I think you are missing the dataframe name before the ['W'], add the dataframe name and `.mul` function works fine i.e  if `geyser_June_e2` is the dataframe name then

```
xcolumn_list1 = geyser_June_e2['W']  
xcolumn_list1.mul(1000)
```

In your case you want to plot the data so as @John Galt said you can multiply directly by 1000 and then plot the data

```
xcolumn_list1 = ['W']
geyser_June_e2[xcolumn_list1] *= 1000
geyser_June_e2[xcolumn_list1].plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, I nearly did it the same way as you suggested in your second solution!

Answer (score 0):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"W":[1,2,3,4,5]})

df*=1000

print(df)

      W
0  1000
1  2000
2  3000
3  4000
4  5000
```

or

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"W":[1,2,3,4,5]})

df.loc[:,"W"]=df.loc[:,"W"]*1000

print(df)

      W
0  1000
1  2000
2  3000
3  4000
4  5000
```

if you have multiple columns and just want to multiply the values of some columns